# How do I capture Radio option value in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I capture the radio option value? When I click to invoke the onChange event, I get an error  `"Expected` onChange`listener to be a function, instead got a value of`object `type."` Thanks

here is the state code here:

```
const [sectionAData, setSectionAData] = useState({})
```

Here is the function code here:

```
  const handleSectionA = (e) => {  
            setSectionAData({ ...sectionAData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
    }
```

Here is the form:

```
 <tr>
        <td style={{ width: "2rem", textAlign: "center" }}>1</td>
        <td style={{padding:"5px"}}>Please rate this product A.</td>
        <td style={{textAlign: "center" }}><input type="radio" name="AQ1" onChange={sectionAData} value="5"/></td>
        <td style={{textAlign: "center" }}><input type="radio" name="AQ1" onChange={sectionAData} value="4"/></td>
        <td style={{textAlign: "center" }}><input type="radio" name="AQ1" onChange={sectionAData} value="3"/></td>
        <td style={{textAlign: "center" }}><input type="radio" name="AQ1" onChange={sectionAData} value="2"/></td>
        <td style={{textAlign: "center" }}><input type="radio" name="AQ1" onChange={sectionAData} value="1"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style={{ width: "2rem", textAlign: "center" }}>2</td>
        <td>Please rate this product B.</td>
        <td style={{textAlign: "center" }}><input type="radio" name="AQ2" onChange={sectionAData} value="5"/></td>
        <td style={{textAlign: "center" }}><input type="radio" name="AQ2" onChange={sectionAData} value="4"/></td>
        <td style={{textAlign: "center" }}><input type="radio" name="AQ2" onChange={sectionAData} value="3"/></td>
        <td style={{textAlign: "center" }}><input type="radio" name="AQ2" onChange={sectionAData} value="2"/></td>
        <td style={{textAlign: "center" }}><input type="radio" name="AQ2" onChange={sectionAData} value="1"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style={{ width: "2rem", textAlign: "center" }}>3</td>
        <td>Please rate this product C.</td>
        <td style={{textAlign: "center" }}><input type="radio" name="AQ3" onChange={sectionAData} value="5"/></td>
        <td style={{textAlign: "center" }}><input type="radio" name="AQ3" onChange={sectionAData} value="4"/></td>
        <td style={{textAlign: "center" }}><input type="radio" name="AQ3" onChange={sectionAData} value="3"/></td>
        <td style={{textAlign: "center" }}><input type="radio" name="AQ3" onChange={sectionAData} value="2"/></td>
        <td style={{textAlign: "center" }}><input type="radio" name="AQ3" onChange={sectionAData} value="1"/></td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `onChange={sectionAData}` to a function, for example your `handleSectionA` function: `onChange={handleSectionA}`.

```
<td style={{ width: "2rem", textAlign: "center" }}>3</td>
<td>Please rate this product C.</td>
<td style={{textAlign: "center" }}><input type="radio" name="AQ3" onChange={handleSectionA} value="5"/></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change in the following way, at ***onChange***:

```
<tr>
        <td style={{ width: "2rem", textAlign: "center" }}>1</td>
        <td style={{padding:"5px"}}>Please rate this product A.</td>
        <td style={{textAlign: "center" }}><input type="radio" name="AQ1" onChange={handleSectionA} value="5"/></td>
        .....
</tr>
```